# Mac OS X Lion (10.7) Drive Encryption

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, filevault

My iMac has two drives (a 256 GB solid-state drive, and regular 2 TB hard drive). The Mac OS X Lion system is installed on the solid-state drive and, like many other users, I have moved my user profile folder onto the secondary 2 TB drive. However, as you may be aware, FileVault 2 on Mac OS X Lion (10.7) only encrypts the system drive. This leaves my data drive (containing my user profile folder, with all of my data) unencrypted.

I am aware that work arounds for this issue exist (such as https://github.com/jridgewell/Unlock) but I am not happy with the results since they involve decrypting the data drive on startup using a LaunchDaemon (before any users have logged into the computer) essentially meaning that any user who logs onto the computer will see the unencrypted drive.

I would like a method which will only unencrypted the data when an authorised user logs into the computer.

As such, is there a way to do one of the following?

1. Encrypt the entire data drive and only decrypt the drive when an authorised user logs into the computer. This would be equivalent behaviour to the Lion FileVault 2 feature, but on a secondary drive rather than the system drive.
2. Encrypt only the user profile folder on the data drive, and only decrypt the folder when the user logs into the computer. This would be equivalent to the behaviour of FileVault 1 on previous versions of Mac OS X?

I am happy to pay for a commercial third-party product that provides the required feature(s), but I have not yet been able to find one.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I would use TrueCrypt to encrypt the entire second drive.

Answer (score 1):

> However, as you may be aware, FileVault 2 on Mac OS X Lion
>   (10.7) only encrypts the system drive

You can encrypt non-system drive with FileVault 2: [10.7: Using FileVault2 to encrypt a second hard drive with user folders System 10.7](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110723223309186)

The secondary hard drive is decrypted after a user logs in (either manually or you could save the drive encryption password in the Keychain).

Edit: make sure that you have good backup before trying that, should you choose to go with that option.